# Display list of tags associated with custom post type

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I am having a hard time to produce a list of tags used for a custom post type.

*** Post type: ***

```
resource
```

*** Tags associated with resource: ***

```
General Information
Communications Committee
Keynote Documents
Policy Postions
```

*** Desired Output: ***

```
<ul>
<li>General Information</li>
<li>Communications Committee</li>
<li>Keynote Documents</li>
<li>Policy Positions</li>
</ul>
```

*** Attempt so far: ***

```
$terms = get_terms( array(
        'taxonomy' => 'resources',
        'hide_empty' => false,
    ) );

print_r($terms);
```

**Results in:**

```
WP_Error Object ( [errors] => Array ( [invalid_taxonomy] => Array (
 [0] => Invalid taxonomy. ) ) [error_data] => Array ( ) )
```

What am I doing wrong here? Why isn't it outputting what I think it should, and how can I get there?

Thanks

Comment: `Resources` isn't your taxonomy, it's your post type. What is the actual taxonomy that those terms fall under? Is it `tags` or is it a custom taxonomy?

Comment: It would be tags if I’m not mistaken

Comment: Well, you need to be sure. So, in the dashboard, I'm going to assume you have a menu item called `Resources` - in the fly out menu if you hover over that, and then hover over the taxonomy name (don't click) and look in the destination URL that appears in the bottom of the browser or right click and copy the link location and paste it. In the URL there will be a parameter `taxonomy=` what's after the `=` sign? That's the taxonomy.

Comment: right after the = is resource_type

Comment: In your attempt code, change `resources` to `resource_type`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the custom post type registered name to the `get_terms` which is why it's not working.

Based on your comments, you need to pass `resource_type` which is the registered taxonomy name.

This is how your term query should look:

```
$terms = get_terms(array(
    'taxonomy' => 'resource_type',
    'hide_empty' => false,
));
```

To output the results as you wish (without links):

```
$terms = get_terms(array(
        'taxonomy' => 'resource_type',
        'hide_empty' => false,
    ));

if ( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {
     echo '<ul>';
     foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
         echo '<li>' . $term->name . '</li>';
     }
     echo '</ul>';
}
```